# Sequence of Iterate Field Values in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I'm pretty new to ModelBuilder and have been working on a tool that separates an exotic vegetation point feature class by species, then separates each species by treatment action, and then date.

I made a model using Iterate Field Values to create a new output feature class for each species in the input feature class.  This portion worked great, but now I want to be able to go through each output feature class and iterate for another field value: treatment action.  I have been researching nested models/integrating a model within a model but have not been successful.  When I try to insert a new iterator, all the options are grayed out.

Here is a screenshot of the model that has worked so far and produced new feature classes for each species (taxon):

[image: Model]

Is there any way to make the output values act as an input for the next iteration?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use two iterators in one model.

Now you can imbed one model inside another model and use two iterators in this manner. The ESRI resource to do this is at this [link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Integrating_a_model_within_a_model/002w0000007p000000/), you have to scroll down to Advanced Use of Model Iterators.

Create two models: a main model and a submodel, where the submodel is nested inside the main model. Both can now have iterators.